# how to open different activities when receiving notification from parse

Tags: android-activity, parse-platform, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have different categories in my app such as **news,weather,sports and** **technology**,I use parse to receive notification ,but i want the notification to be customized in which once a notification **regarding news is received it should open news activity,if notification regarding technology is received it should open technology activity.**
  I don't want custom push receiver,i tried lots of examples but i can't get it.any ideas thanks in advance

Comment: First you have to set your app to receive notifications and handle them (in your manifest, you have to add those intents who deals with receiving data from push):
https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing
Second, you can get the idea how to do that from the docs:
https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-receiving-pushes
If you need more help, please let me know. Btw i also want to do this in my application, but i haven't done it yet, if your patient enough, i'll share the code with you.

Comment: okay i'll try and let u know

Answer (score 3):

First you need to create a custom class that extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.
and in that class you Override onPushOpen method:

```
public class ParsePushCustomReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

protected  static  String pushTitle="";

@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushOpen(context, intent);

    pushTitle="";
    try {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
            JSONObject json;
            json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            pushTitle = json.getString("title");
            String pushContent = json.getString("alert");
      //intent to your activity

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Now when you have the title and the content of the push you can direct to the activity that you want to go...

You need to define your custom ParsePushBroadcastReceiver as reciever in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <!-- Parse PushService-->
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.appname.appname.ParsePushCustomReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.appname.appname" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```